# When using gnome, how can I increase the separation between workspaces

Tags: gnome, workspaces

My problem with using workspaces in Gnome is with keeping programs separated between workspaces.

When I for example start up a software in workspace 1 then move on to workspace 2 before the program has opened the opened program follows me to workspace 2. This is a big problem when programs automatically start other programs or wait for a specific event to happen before they open as I really want my workspaces to be structured and it will get really messy otherwise.

The second issue I have with workspaces is that whenever there is an event in a program in another workspace I get a blinking icon in my toolbar from that software. I really don't want this. For example, I have multiple gnuplots monitoring some programs that run on other workspaces. As they update every minute, they constantly clog up my toolbar in the other workspaces.

Can I increase my "separation" between the workspaces, making what happens in workspace 1 stay in workspace 1 so I can get a much more structured work environment?